# Hover over one object and affect another using CSS (Not jquery)

Tags: css

How do I hover over one object and affect something else? In my code, I am trying to get a dropdown comedown when I hover over the down arrow. I am trying to do it with CSS and not jquery or JS.

[SEE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/45pvptwy/2/)

HTML

```
<span class="MyDropDown">Menu Name
    <ul class="MyDropDownList">
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul> 
</span>
```

JS

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('MyDropDown');
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var s = x[i].innerHTML.split("<")[0];
    var l = '<' + x[i].innerHTML.split("<")[1];
    x[i].innerHTML = '<table>\n<tr>\n<td>' + s + '</td>\n<td><div></div></td>\n</tr>\n</table>\n' + l;
}
```

CSS

```
.MyDropDown {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.MyDropDown td:nth-child(1) {
    padding:5px 15px;
    border-right:1px solid #777777;
}
.MyDropDown td:nth-child(1):hover {
    color:#CCC;
}

.MyDropDown div:first-child {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 4px solid #FFF;
}
.MyDropDown ul {
    display:none;
}
.MyDropDown td:nth-child(2):hover > div:first-child {
    border-top-color:#CCC;
}
.MyDropDown td:nth-child(2):hover > td:first-child{ /*this one*/
    border-bottom:1px solid #777777;
}
.MyDropDown td:nth-child(2):hover > ul { /*this one*/
    display:block;
    min-height:15px;
}
```

Comment: You can affect something below the element being hovered on by doing `#elt:hover #affected-elt` or similar, but otherwise, no.

Comment: `.MyDropDown:hover ul { display:block; }`

Comment: if you're not looking for how to show the menu when the arrow is hovered exclusively , than use @APAD1 suggestion. otherwise you'd have to change your markup

Comment: @APAD1 I want it to only drop when I am over the arrow and not the text.

Comment: @Makai, could you give me some feedback please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only hovering on the arrow right?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/b8nt16eo/

```
div.menu > div.arrow:hover + ul {
    display: block;
}
```